# Checking if a text file is formatted in a specific way

Tags: ruby, io

I have a text file which contains instructions. I'm reading it using `File.readlines(filename)`. I want to check that the file is formatted as follows:

- Has 3 lines
- Line 1: two integers (including negatives) separated by a space
- Line 2: two integers (including negatives) separated by a space and 1 capitalised letter of the alphabet also separated by a space.
- Line 3: capitalised letters of the alphabet without any spaces (or punctuation).

This is what the file should look like:

```
8 10
1 2 E
MMLMRMMRRMML
```

So far I have calculated the number of lines using `File.readlines(filename).length`. How do I check the format of each line, do I need to loop through the file?

EDIT:
I solved the problem by creating three methods containing regular expressions, then I passed each line into it's function and created a conditional statement to check if the out put was true.

Comment: If you still want help, then post your attempt. If you don't need a solution any more, then make your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose [IO::read](https://apidock.com/ruby/v2_5_5/IO/read/class) is used to return the following string `str`.

```
str = <<~END
8 10
1 2 E
MMLMRMMRRMML
END
  #=> "8 10\n1 2 E\nMMLMRMMRRMML\n"
```

You can then test the string with a single regular expression:

```
r = /\A(-?\d+) \g<1>\n\g<1> \g<1> [A-Z]\n[A-Z]+\n\z/
```

```
str.match?(r)
  #=> true
```

I could have written

```
r = /\A-?\d+ -?\d+\n-?\d+ -?\d+ [A-Z]\n[A-Z]+\n\z/
```

but matching an integer (`-?\d+`) is done three times. It's slightly shorter, and reduces the chance of error, to put the first of the three in capture group 1, and then treat that as a *subexpression* by calling it with `\g<1>` (not to be confused with a *back-reference*, which is written `\k<1>`). Alternatively, I could have use named capture groups:

```
r = /\A(?<int>-?\d+) \g<int>\n\g<int> \g<int> (?<cap>[A-Z])\n\g<cap>+\n\z/
```

Comment: Thanks, Cary! I ended up doing something similar shortly after I posted the question. I did exactly what you posted but used three methods to match the string. I could have used a single one but it was for a code challenge so I thought that naming the methods according to what they do would show that I know what I'm doing.